# Laravel: How to run a Library in background (Process component)

Tags: laravel, process, background, shell-exec

I'm trying to create a program which generates event dates for the whole year. The program works if the user select few events but if the user select 100+ events and assigned them every week it reaches the Maximum execution time error.

In order to fix this, my idea is to run the program in the background.

I'm using Laravel 5.4, running the script below will call the function

```
$process = new Process('php -f '.$path.' generate_evnt_prepared ' . $content['evntid']);
$process->run();
```

Function Script

```
namespace App\Library\shellexec;

use App\Model\V1\EvntPlanDtl;
use App\Model\V1\EvntPlanDtlPrePo;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class RoutePlan {
//put your code here

public function process($method = null, $param = 0)
{
    $this->$method($param);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the function is called as I'm getting an error in error_logs that the Models are not found

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Model\V1\EvntPlanDtl' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\rdmsoffice\app\Library\shellexec\EventPlan.php on line 30
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\rdmsoffice\app\Library\shellexec\EventPlan.php:0
PHP   2. App\Library\shellexec\EventPlan->process() C:\xampp\htdocs\rdmsoffice\app\Library\shellexec\EventPlan.php:88
PHP   3. App\Library\shellexec\EventPlan->generate_evnt_prepared ()
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? I'm open to suggestions if this is the wrong way.

Big thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues laravel pretty much has that without you needing the problem of configuring accesses and stuff

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a more scalable way is to create a "chunked" version and fire them into a queue for processing. For example, based off some assumptions about the  example you provided, I might suggest one firing one queued message for each Event the user selects.

That adds some overhead to manage, but honestly I've always found it's more effective to take some of that cost up front and do it right, rather than finding workarounds like increasing settings or (shudder) shelling out to sub processes.